# mysql order by matches in comma separated field

Tags: php, mysql

I have one blog table which contains different tags,

now i want to order blog by max tag match

and am storing tags comma separated in one field

now how to do that?

I tried **find in set** but still dident get work.

Please suggest me any better way to do so.

table like:

```
id | title | desc      | tags

1 | test1 | test1 desc | t1,t2,t3,t4

2 | test2 | test desc  | t1,t2

3 | test3 | test desc  | t1,t2,t3

4 | test4 | test desc  | t3,t4

5 | test5 | test desc  | t1,t2,t3,t4
```

here suppose i want closest blog post of **"test1"** post then answer should be 
**5,3,2,4**

first match with tags and after that if same tag count then by id

Comment: Please post some sample data along with the desired output.

Comment: Can you change your DB design? It would be better to store the tags seperately.

Comment: Store your tags in another table and then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329853/find-related-topics-in-mysql

Comment: is there any solution with present condition?

Comment: First select data into into PHP: 1) test1, and 2) records to compare. Then loop through the records to compare, and for each record apply `array_diff` to the test1 tags and the current record tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354109/mysql-order-by-max-matches-field-value

Comment: please keep this one open if i will get solution for this then that will be best for me

Comment: @Er.KT have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first separate tags into a different table.